# Graph theory: creating surfaces

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves, geometric-topology, plane-geometry

**If we draw a circle in the plane , we separate the plane into 2 regions , inside and outside.**

On the following surfaces, determine the maximal number of circles that you can draw on the surface without creating more than one region : **Sphere, Torus , Pretzel(double -doughnut), Klein bottle and a projective plane**.

Honestly I don't see how is it possible to draw a circle(with radius > 0) on one of these surfaces without creating more than 1 region. A circle on a sphere is a Sphere-plane intersection. So if you draw a circle on a sphere you will create 2 regions, one above the plane and one below

Comment: This is really a topology question, I think. I could see applications to graph theory, perhaps.

Comment: Nothing has been covered in the lectures regarding topology :/ (There is no topic related to topology in the book)

Comment: Have you been given definitions of the Klein bottle and the projective plane? What do you know about them?

Comment: I know their shapes and diagrams(that's it)
Klein Bottle:  square with one pair of opposing sides identified, and other pair identified "the wrong way round"

Projective plane: square where both pairs of sides are identified wrong way around

Comment: Well, that's topology, whether the book calls it that or not. You can get the answer by analyzing those squares-with-identifications. Just note that drawing a line straight through the middle of the square, horizontally or vertically, is equivalent to drawing a circle on the surface represented. On the torus, for example, you can draw a horizontal stripe and a vertical stripe, and still get from any point to any other point through the identified sides without crossing your stripes. Do you see that?

Comment: I understood some part of it but not whole. Can you mention some link or source where I can read about it in detail?

Comment: Honestly I don't see how is it possible to draw a circle(with radius > 0) on one of these surfaces without creating more than 1 region.
A circle on a sphere is a Sphere-plane intersection. So if you draw a circle on a sphere you will create 2 regions, one above the plane and one below

Comment: You're right about the sphere. It's different though on a torus. Imagine taking an inner tube, and cutting it along a circle that runs through the center hole. Such a cut would just turn the torus into a tube, or cylinder. It's like inserting a knife into a donut hole and then just cutting outward through the donut in one direction. That cut, on the surface of the donut, is a circle.

Comment: So, there are infinite circles for a torus? because you can make a cut where-ever you want

Comment: No. If you make two cuts on a donut just like the one I described, you will separate the donut into two pieces. You can get away with a second one, but it has to run along the inside of the donut hole... latitudinally as it were. With those two cuts made, the surface of the donut peels open into a rectangle - the very square on which you made identifications to make a torus in the first place.

Comment: That's another good way to think of it: When you identify a square along opposite sides to make a torus, leave visible stripes where the identifications occur. Then you'll have two circles painted on the outside of your torus, intersecting at right angles. Any more cuts, and you'll start separating regions.

Comment: So, it should be 2 circles for torus.
One just like you said just cutting outward through the donut in one direction and other one as a horizontal slice.

With those two circles you can still go everywhere on the torus without crossing a line. But if you add one more circle it's over, you have split the torus in regions.

Comment: I thought about the Klein Bottle, I stared at a picture of a klein bottle for about 2 minutes thinking of how could I draw circles on it and my guess is that you can draw one circle (for exampe around the neck, on the inside or outsite) without splitting the surface into regions. But I'm not sure.

Comment: It's hard to see with a Klein bottle, but I think it works the same as a torus - the two identifications on the square that create the Klein bottle can be your two cuts, which return to to a connected rectangle that is still one region.

Comment: Any help for Pretzel(double -doughnut) and a projective plane? I tried but i am running out of ideas.